# Is it possible to create azure file share mount on WebJobs VM?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-storage-files

Can I use net-use to create a mount inside a **Webjobs Virtual Machine**?
It usually has `C:` & `D:` drives. I get an `access denied` error!

```
Z:\ net use [drive letter]: \\[storage account name].file.core.windows.net\[share name] /u:[storage account name]   [storage account key]
```

Comment: What do you mean Webjobs Virtual Machine? Do you mean Virtual Machine: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/virtual-machines/ or Azure Web Jobs: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you recieve an access denied error and [the sandbox description](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox)  say "Applications are highly restricted in terms of their access of the file system." and only list  d:\home and d:\local i would say its very unlikely.

Comment: I confirm that this is not currently possible. But it could become later.